# glMultiDrawElements VBOs

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a model i want to render with glMultiDrawElements. Preparing the data and rendering it using simple vectors works fine, but fails when i use vertex buffers. Apparently i make some kind of mistake when calculating the buffer offsets. First the working code:

I a first step i prepare the data for later use (contains pseudo code to make it easier to read):

```
for(each face in the model){
    const Face &f = *face;

    drawSizes.push_back(3);

    for(int i=0;i<f.numberVertices;++i){
        const Vertex &v = vertices[f.vertices[i]]]; // points to vertex array
    vertexArray.push_back(v.x);
    indexArray.push_back(vertexArray.size() - 1);
    vertexArray.push_back(v.y);
    indexArray.push_back(vertexArray.size() - 1);
    vertexArray.push_back(v.z);
    indexArray.push_back(vertexArray.size() - 1);

    normalArray.push_back(f.normalx);
    normalArray.push_back(f.normaly);
    normalArray.push_back(f.normalz);
    }
}

int counter = 0;

for(each face in the model){
    vertexIndexStart.push_back(&indexArray[counter*3]);
    offsetIndexArray.push_back(static_cast<void*>(0) + counter*3);
    counter++;
}

drawSizes is a vector<Glint>
vertexArray is a vector<GLfloat>
indexArray is a vector<GLint>
vertexIndexStart is a vector<Glvoid *>
offsetIndexArray is a vector<GLvoid *>
```

I now draw this with the glMultiDrawElements-function in the following way:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,3*sizeof(GLfloat),&vertexArray[0]);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT,0,&normalArray[0]);
glMultiDrawElements(GL_POLYGON,&drawSizes[0],GL_UNSIGNED_INT,&vertexIndexStart[0],vertexIndexStart.size());
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
```

and it draws the model just as it should, altough the performance is not that much better than the immediate mode.

When i now try to buffer the created data and render the model using buffers it apparently does not work. Again in a first step i preprocess the already processed data:

```
glGenBuffers(2,buffers);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vertexArray),&vertexArray[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indexArray),&indexArray[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);

buffers is a GLuint[]
```

Then i try to render the data:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
glVertexPointer(3,GL_FLOAT,3*sizeof(GLfloat),0);
glMultiDrawElements(GL_POLYGON,&drawSizes[0],GL_UNSIGNED_INT,&offsetIndexArray[0],vertexIndexStart.size());
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

which leads to an empty screen. Any ideas?

Edit: I now use the correct indices as suggested but i still don't get the desired result.

Comment: Do not use multidraw elements such that each individual draw is only 3 vertices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffers[1]);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexIndexStart),&vertexIndexStart[0],GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
```

The element array buffer should contain the *index array*, which means the indices into the vertex arrays, not the indices into the index array.

Please also note that your code is using lots of deprecated GL features (builtin attributes, probably even the fixed-function pipeline, drawing without VAOs), and will not work in a core profile of modern OpenGL.

Speaking of modern GL: That further level of indirection, where the parameter array for `glMultiDrawElements` itself comes from a buffer object,  is even supported in modern GL via [`glMultiDrawElemetnsIndirect`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glMultiDrawElementsIndirect.xhtml).

Comment: I changed the code so that the vertices are passed to the buffer, but i still have no rendering of the model. Is the offset buffer i create correct? And what would be a better way than fixed-function? Using shaders?

Comment: What do you mean by " the vertices are passed to the buffer"? YOu need to pass the index array. Also, youe whole approach is very inefficient. you are basically tring to draw each face separately. You should just build a vertex and index array for the whole object. This would completely eliminate the need for `MultiDraw...` in the first place. Using modern GL requires shaders, yes, but there is a lot more.

Comment: I already wrote a shader that emulates the fixed function pipeline, but i'd rather try to figure this out first. I meant i'm passing the index array now. I think the problem is the offset array.

Comment: Yes, you forgot to multiply the offsets by `sizeof(GLuint)`.

Comment: This `glMultiDrawElements(GL_POLYGON, ...` is definitely wrong. The GL_POLYGON has nothing to do with `mode` enumerator, which needs to be one of GL_POINTS, GL_LINE_STRIP, GL_LINE_LOOP, GL_LINES, GL_LINE_STRIP_ADJACENCY, GL_LINES_ADJACENCY, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, GL_TRIANGLES, GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP_ADJACENCY, GL_TRIANGLES_ADJACENCY and GL_PATCHES (or its reduced subset for OpenGL 3.2+). Probably, you are drawing some unwanted type of primitive which `mode` value co-incidentally equals to GL_POLYGON value.

Comment: `GL_POLYGON` is a valid primitive type in legacy GL, and the code in question uses legacy GL all other the place. There are also no GL enum collisions, they are all unique.